# JS: $addToSet or $pull depending on existing/missing value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I need to add or remove an ID from an array (`target`), depending if it is already existing. This is how I am doing this:

```
var isExisting = Articles.findOne({ _id }).target.indexOf(mID) > -1

if (isExisting === false) {
  Articles.update(
      { _id },
      { $addToSet: { target: mID } }
    )
} else if (isExisting === true) {
  Articles.update(
    { _id },
    { $pull: { target: mID } }
  )
}
```

Is it possible to do this in a better way - without doing if/else and min. two db operations?

Comment: I doubt you are doing it like that since the database methods are actually "async" and therefore cannot return values the way you demonstrate. Meteor perhaps? Also I'm not sure I follow your logic since you basically say you want to "add" where it does not exist or "remove" when it does exist, which seems somewhat confusing in intent. So the whole thing looks more like "psuedocode"  than something real, and could do with an actual example of what you need to do instead. It's certainly possible to do multiple operations in one request. But I have no idea what you actually want to do.

Comment: You are right, I'm using Meteor. Forgot the tag for that. And yes, this is my real code. I'm using that in productive and it is working, but it feels very bad, so I would like to optimize that...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is my suggestion

```
let isExisting = Articles.findOne({ _id: _id, target : mID}) //mongo can search for mID in array of [mIDs]
let query = { _id : _id };
let update = isExisting ? { $pull: { target: mID } } : { $addToSet: { target: mID } };

Articles.update(query, update);
```

is it better and clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose operations are asynchronous, so you need to wait for its callback to get the document.

```
// find the article by its ID
Articles.findById(_id, function (err, article) {
    // make appropriate change depending on whether mID exist in the article's target
    if (article.target.indexOf(mID) > -1)
        article.target.pull(mID)
    else
        article.target.push(mID)
    // commit the change
    article.save(function (err) {

    });
})
```

Although you are doing if/else, you are doing 2 operations.